# If $X \supseteq B \supseteq A$, then $B/A$ subspace of $X/A$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Problem 4.3.3 in Ronnie Brown's *Topology and Groupoids* asks

> Let $A, B$ be subsets of $X$ such that $A$ is closed and $A \subseteq
>  B$. Show that $B/A$ is a subspace of $X/A$.

I think I have solved it, but I'm puzzled because it seems that the hypothesis that $A$ is closed is unnecessary, so I wanted to be sure I'm not missing something.

We want to show that $B/A$ carries the same topology whether we first consider the subspace topology then the quotient topology or the other way around. This is, I believe, equivalent to showing that if $p:X \to X/A$ is the quotient map, then $q = p|_B : B \to p(B)$ is itself a quotient map. But this is true since if $U \subseteq B$ is open in $B$ and $q$-saturated, then $U = W \cap B$ for some $W$ open in $X$, an $W$ has no choice but to be $p$-saturated since $B \supseteq A$.

Is there any error in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. One can generalize this a bit.

> Let $X$ be a space with an equivalence relation $R$, and let $B\subset X$ be a subset such that $B\times B$ contains $R\setminus\Delta_X$, then the quotient map $q:X\to X/R$ restricts to a quotient map $q':B\to q(B)$.

One proves this by taking a closed $q'$-saturated set $C$ in $B$. Then $C=B\cap \overline C$ and the closure $\overline C$ is $q$-saturated.

So one could say, if $B$ contains all identifications, then $B/R$ is a subspace of $X/R$.

Comment: Similarly, an exercise says to show that $X/B \approx (X/A)/(B/A)$, but has the hypothesis that B is closed, which seems unnecessary, since a set in $X$ is saturated with respect to one map iff it is saturated with respect to the other. Do you agree? Thanks

Comment: @EricAuld: I agree.